# The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to upload files to the cloud storage in Wasabi, but I can't. This error comes out:
An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
I checked the key several times, everything is correct. The strange thing is that before that I tried to create a new basket and everything worked out for me, but I can't upload the files.

```
    import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  endpoint_url='https://s3.wasabisys.com',
                  aws_access_key_id="********R2PN",
                  aws_secret_access_key="*************zDKnnWS")


file_path = r"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Programming\rofls_with_node\tracks.txt"
bucket_name = "last-fm9"
key_name = "tracks.txt"
s3.put_object(Body=file_path, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
```

Comment: Sounds like the access key you are supplying is either invalid (e.g. corrupted in some way) or does not actually exist as a valid access key in wasabi.

Comment: Are you able to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with those credentials, using `aws s3 ls `--endpoint-url=https://s3.wasabisys.com`? It will be a good way to test whether the credentials are correct. See: [How do I use AWS CLI with Wasabi? – Wasabi Knowledge Base](https://wasabi-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001910791-How-do-I-use-AWS-CLI-with-Wasabi-)

Comment: I used the command "aws s3 ls --endpoint-url = s3.wasabisys.com" and at first I got the same answer saying that there was no key. But then I typed in "aws config", left the keys the same, but changed the region to "us-east-1", and tried to send the same request, and I got a normal response. But I still can't send files because of the key.

Answer (score 2):

That's it, I solved the problem, I just had to change endpoint_url to "https://s3.us-east-2.wasabisys.com" (instead of us-east-2, insert the region of your basket). Thanl

Comment: struggled for this whole morning thank you very much and most definitely their should be another type exception to let user know that the region is incorrect